# How to generate magnolia bootstrap files?

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I cloned some magnolia content app examples and can't understand, how to generate magnolia bootstrap xml files. They are too big and to write them manually is too hard. 
I think there is a way to generate them automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnolia Bootstrap Files are created within Magnolia. Just create the content you want to bootstrap and export it. Some Apps like the pages app or the config app have an "export" action in the action bar. It is also possible to use the [export app](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Export+app) to create bootstrap files for all kinds of magnolia workspaces.

Comment: export app is not available for newer Magnolia Version (>5.3). You can use export actions direct in various apps, like Jan mentions. Or with the Jcr Tools app.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas said, you should not hand write bootstrap files, but instead export configuration or data you want to bootstrap from Magnolia.
Since "what you want" seems to be creation of apps, you might want to look at a script to create them (so you can them export such created app as a bootstrap file) mentioned [here](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blogs/jan-haderka/detail~@a-geeky-script-to-speed-up-your-app-development~.html).

HTH,
Jan